# Can't read Arabic PDF file with custom font

Tags: java, arabic

I have an Arabic PDF file which contains a custom font, so when I try to read the file I faced some unreadable words and characters replaced with another character or symbol.

Here is the [link to the PDF file I'm working on](https://drive.google.com/file/d/159vooN7L0poKQdUeCvt8Co_VfpNxynEz/view?usp=sharing).

```
public class TikaAnalysis {
    public static String extractContentUsingFacade(InputStream stream) throws IOException, TikaException {
        Tika tika = new Tika();
        String content = tika.parseToString(stream);
        try {
            WriteOnWordDoc(str);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return content;
    }

    public static void WriteOnWordDoc(String fileContent) throws Exception {
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
        XWPFParagraph tmpParagraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun tmpRun = tmpParagraph.createRun();
        tmpRun.setText(fileContent);
        tmpRun.setFontSize(10);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("extractedContent.docx"));
        document.write(fos);
        fos.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FileInputStream  inputStream = null;
        String path ="File.pdf";
        try {
            File file=new File(path);
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
            TikaAnalysis.extractContentUsingFacade(inputStream);
            inputStream.close();    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("close the file  ");
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the Tika class? How are you reading the pdf file? In the line " WriteOnWordDoc(str);" where is the str variable?

Comment: i am already mentioned the Tika method that i am using at above code "extractContentUsingFacade" and have an stream. and about the reading the file i am reading the file direct from the main class . and about write the file you can use the content instead of str